# It there any way to set/get data in konva shape?

Tags: konvajs

It there any way to set/get data in konva object?

Just like jquery use the method `'data'` to set and get info,**eg:** `$('#abc').data('id','123')` !

Comment: Hi and welcome - looks like you have a viable answer from @lavrton below. If this works for you then please click the tick to mark it as the accepted answer. If not then add a comment on that answer and help us to know why it will not work for you so that we can suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use custom attributes. Just make sure they don't overlap with built-in properties.

https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Node.html#setAttr

https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Node.html#getAttr

```
// set
shape.setAttr('someData', 0);
// get
shape.getAttr('someData');
```

Comment: Thank you for your quickly reply!